# installed .NET versions

Tags: windows-10, .net-framework

SO after migrating to a new PC, Win 10 Pro, Visual Studio tells me it cannot load a project because .NET 4.5 isn't registered within IIS. Other answers on this site have suggested a command prompt fix ([here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13749138/asp-net-4-5-has-not-been-registered-on-the-web-server)) but when I tried that it tells me the command is not supported, and I should use the Add/Remove Windows Features feature (within Control Panel)... but that only offers me versions 3.5 and 4.7, which are already ticked and installed.  And in my C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64 folder I see v2.2.50727, v3.0, v3.5 and v4.0.30319 - and these are just as on my old machine, which has v4.5 working.

In fact the "Turn Windows features on or off" settings are exactly the same on both machines, showing 3.5 and 4.7.

So how can I enable 4.5? I would have thought that if 4.7 is installed then earlier versions would be too, but evidently not... if I download and install 4.5 from the MS site will that bugger up what's already installed to that v4.0.30319 folder?

Thanks....

Answer (score 0):

OK - I should have read the comments closer on the article I linked to!  Downloading and installing the VS2012 update mentioned there fixed the issue :)